# Reading Facebook's Public Posts and User Profiles using Graph API in RestFB ?

Tags: facebook, restfb

I want to ready ONLY public Posts and User's profiles of those Posts from Facebook using Graph (search) API.

And I am little confused over which access token I need , do I need User Access Token or Application Access Token ?

My application is Java based console/desktop application and I am using RestFB.

Please guide me here to how to get my required information and most importantly if I require a User Access Token , then how can I automate this process in my application using RestFB (or any other Java Facebook lib)?

Please note that this is a console application (will run on server) not a client application so what I can do is to create a dummy facebook user account and generate User Access Token using that dummy account.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: `public Posts and User's profiles of those Posts `- which posts? Your requirement is quite unclear.

Comment: The posts I have searched using GRAPH API.

Comment: Are you using `search` API or a `page` feed ? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try read the documentation about tokens, you have four types of tokens. See what suits best for you.

> **User Access Token** – The user token is the most commonly used type of
>   token. This kind of access token is needed any time the app calls an
>   API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook data on
>   their behalf. User access tokens are generally obtained via a login
>   dialog and require a person to permit your app to obtain one.

---

> **App Access Token** – This kind of access token is needed to modify and
>   read the app settings. It can also be used to publish Open Graph
>   actions. It is generated using a pre-agreed secret between the app and
>   Facebook and is then used during calls that change app-wide settings.
>   You obtain an app access token via a server-to-server call.

---

> **Page Access Token** – These access tokens are similar to user access
>   tokens, except that they provide permission to APIs that read, write
>   or modify the data belonging to a Facebook Page. To obtain a page
>   access token you need to start by obtaining a user access token and
>   asking for the manage_pages permission. Once you have the user access
>   token you then get the page access token via the Graph API.

---

> **Client Token** - The client token is an identifier that you can embed
>   into native mobile binaries or desktop apps to identify your app. The
>   client token isn't meant to be a secret identifier because it's
>   embedded in applications. The client token is used to access app-level
>   APIs, but only a very limited subset. The client token is found in
>   your app's dashboard. Since the client token is used rarely, we won't
>   talk about it in this document. Instead it's covered in any API
>   documentation that uses the client token.

---

You can read a more detailed info of each token here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

If this is much complex for you, you can get the public posts of pages using rss feed. You either can have a xml or a json format.

**XML**  `https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=rss20`
**JSON** `https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=json`

Where the PAGE_ID is the id of the page you desire, for example this two urls give you the public posts of John Frusciante's page

**XML** -> https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=122854921087972&format=rss20

**JSON** -> https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=122854921087972&format=json

Comment: Thanks Fabio, it seems I need User Access Token. I have converted my Short-Lived User Access Token to Long-Lived Token. But I am little confused over its expiration... If I use this token daily to call Graph API, would it never expire ??? And one more question to get the user stats like fans , likes , posts etc on any public facebook fanpage... which Access Token & Graph API I would have to use ?

Comment: No, the max a user token lasts is 60 days for security reasons.

Comment: I converted my Short-Lived Token to Long-Lived last week and technically it should show me that my expiry is 60 - 7 = 53 days ... but its showing me 58 days... So I was wondering did it automatically refresh its expiry ?

Comment: maybe somewhere on your process you requested a new token since the token doesn't renew automatically without user interaction

Comment: Hmm well I tested again today the expiry of my Long Lived User Access Token and its showing me again 58 days... So I think its Facebook is somehow refreshing me Access Token on usage !!!